# Pizza Class. Add a set named setOfToppings as an attribute. using Java

Tags: java, enums, set

I basically need a set to be added to what I already have to allow the 'customer' to add or remove toppings once the pizza is created. here is what I already have:

```
package pizza;

public class Pizza {

// Declare enums
public enum Size{
   SMALL,
   MEDIUM,
   LARGE,
   JUMBO
}

public enum Crust{
   CHEESY,
   HAND_TOSSEDS,
   THIN_AND_CRISPY,
   DEEP_PAN
}

 public enum Topping{
   MUSHROOMS,
   GREEN_PEPPERS,
   HAM,
   PEPPERONI,
   SAUGSAGE
}


 // declare variables
 private Size pizzaSize;
 private Crust crustType;

private Set<Topping> setOfToppings = new EnumSet<Topping>(Topping.class);

 public Pizza(){

}

public Pizza(Size pizzaSize, Crust crustType) {
   this.pizzaSize = pizzaSize;
   this.crustType = crustType;
}

 public Size getPizzaSize() {
   return pizzaSize;
}
 public void setPizzaSize(Size pizzaSize) {
   this.pizzaSize = pizzaSize;
}
 public Crust getCrustType() {
   return crustType;
}
 public void setCrustType(Crust crustType) {
   this.crustType = crustType;
}

 public String toString(){
   return "A "+pizzaSize+" Pizza with "+crustType+" crust" + "with topping: " + setOfToppings;
}


}
```

here is the Test Code:

```
package pizza;
import pizza.Pizza.Crust;
import pizza.Pizza.Size;

public class PizzaTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 // use constructor 1
   Pizza vegieCrunch = new Pizza(); 
   vegieCrunch.setCrustType(Crust.THIN_AND_CRISPY);
   vegieCrunch.setPizzaSize(Size.MEDIUM);

 // constructor 2
   Pizza doubleCheese = new Pizza(Size.LARGE, Crust.CHEESY);

   Pizza PartyPizza = new Pizza(Size.JUMBO, Crust.DEEP_PAN);

   // use of getters
   System.out.println("Pizza Vegie Crunch::");
   System.out.println("Size: "+vegieCrunch.getPizzaSize());
   System.out.println("Crust Type: "+vegieCrunch.getCrustType());

   // use of toString
   System.out.println("\nPizza Double Cheese:");
   System.out.println(doubleCheese.toString());

   System.out.println("\nPizza Country Feast:");
   System.out.println(PartyPizza.toString());

   }

    }
```

The current code that I have works great, i just need help with adding an additional Enum Toppings and add a set named setOfToppings so that when I test it the ' customer' can add or remove toppings once the pizza is created. Thank you in advance, I am relatively new to java so any tips or advice is also welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***[...] I just need help with adding an additional enum `Toppings`***

The same way as you defined your other enums:

```
public enum Topping {
   PINEAPPLE,
   BANANA
}
```

> ***[...] and add a set named `setOfToppings`***

Then add a field:

```
private Set<Topping> setOfToppings = EnumSet.noneOf(Topping.class);
```

You can create access methods such as

```
public void addTopping(Topping topping) {
    setOfToppings.add(topping);
}

public Set<Topping> getToppings() {
    return setOfToppings;
}

public void addManyToppings(Topping... toppings) {
    setOfToppings.addAll(Arrays.asList(toppings));
}
```

Comment: I get an error when i add the field:private Set<Topping> setOfToppings = new EnumSet<Topping>(Topping.class);                       Saying the following: Cannot instantiate the type EnumSet<Pizza.Topping>

Comment: Also how should I add the Toppings into the test portion? And thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the update can you give me an example of what you mean for the adding a set?

Comment: you do `doubleCheese.addTopping(Topping.BANANA)` for instance. You may want to update the `toString` method and add `"with topping: " + setOfTopping`.

Comment: Im sorry I meant, for the add a set named setOfToppings, So I go through and do pizza.addTopping(Topping.MUSHROOMS) for each topping?

Comment: Also how do I start off the set statement?

Comment: I updated my original code if that helps you figure out what I am talking about.

Comment: answer updated. You should be able to do `doubleCheese.addManyToppings(Topping.BANANA, Topping.PINEAPPLE);`

Comment: Okay thanks that would be less typing. Where do I add that at?

Comment: I am also still getting the original error, I dont understand how to start off my set statement?

Comment: I updated the answer. You shouldn't use `new EnumSet`.

Comment: I am accepting this answer it was the most help that I have gotten I have been using other websites so thank you! How can I add this new portion of code to my TestCode?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? (Or even better, post a new one specifying what the current problem is. This comment section is not intended for lengthy discussions.) If you post the link to the follow-up question here, I'll have a look at it right away.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445729/need-help-writing-in-a-set-for-my-pizza-code

Comment: that is the link for my new question, thanks for all of your help