# Need help writing in a set for my pizza code

Tags: java, enums, set

Here is my current code. I need help with getting the set list to work in the pizza and the test code.

```
package pizza;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

import pizza.Pizza.Crust;
import pizza.Pizza.Size;
import pizza.Pizza.Topping;

public class Pizza {

// Declare enums
public enum Size{
   SMALL,
   MEDIUM,
   LARGE,
   JUMBO
 }

 public enum Crust{
   CHEESY,
   HAND_TOSSEDS,
   THIN_AND_CRISPY,
   DEEP_PAN
  }

 public enum Topping{
   MUSHROOMS,
   GREEN_PEPPERS,
   HAM,
   PEPPERONI,
   SAUGSAGE
 }

 // declare variables
 private Size pizzaSize;
 private Crust crustType;


 private Set<Topping> setOfToppings = EnumSet.noneOf(Topping.class);
 public Pizza(){


 }
 public void addTopping(Topping topping) {
    setOfToppings.add(topping);
 }

 public Set<Topping> getToppings() {
    return setOfToppings;
 }
 public Pizza(Size pizzaSize, Crust 
  crustType, Topping greenPeppers, Topping saugsage, Topping                
   pepperoni) {
   this.pizzaSize = pizzaSize;
   this.crustType = crustType;


 }

  public Pizza(Size large, Crust cheesy, Topping greenPeppers) {
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 public Size getPizzaSize() {
   return pizzaSize;
 }
 public void setPizzaSize(Size pizzaSize) {
   this.pizzaSize = pizzaSize;
 }
 public Crust getCrustType() {
   return crustType;
 }
 public void setCrustType(Crust crustType) {
   this.crustType = crustType;
 }

 public String toString(){
   return "A "+pizzaSize+" Pizza with "+ crustType +" crust" + "with " + 
  setOfToppings +      "Toppings";
 }


 }
```

Here is my TestCode

```
package pizza;

import pizza.Pizza.Crust;
import pizza.Pizza.Size;
import pizza.Pizza.Topping;

public class PizzaTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // use constructor 1
   Pizza vegieCrunch = new Pizza(); 
   vegieCrunch.setCrustType(Crust.THIN_AND_CRISPY);
   vegieCrunch.setPizzaSize(Size.MEDIUM);
   vegieCrunch.addTopping(Topping.MUSHROOMS);

   // constructor 2
   Pizza doubleCheese = new Pizza(Size.LARGE, Crust.CHEESY, Topping.GREEN_PEPPERS);

   Pizza PartyPizza = new Pizza(Size.JUMBO, Crust.DEEP_PAN, Topping.HAM,
    Topping.SAUGSAGE,   Topping.PEPPERONI);

   // use of getters
   System.out.println("Pizza Vegie Crunch::");
   System.out.println("Size: "+vegieCrunch.getPizzaSize());
   System.out.println("Crust Type: "+vegieCrunch.getCrustType());
   System.out.println("Toppings Chosen: " + vegieCrunch.getToppings());

   // use of toString
   System.out.println("\nPizza Double Cheese:");
   System.out.println(doubleCheese.toString());

   System.out.println("\nPizza Party Pizza:");
   System.out.println(PartyPizza.toString());

 }

}
```

So far it compiles and runs fine however I dont have the add or remove toppings option for the user. I really need help with this, Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Your question is still a bit broad. What specifically confuses you? As written your question is somewhat homework-dumpish because it's basically, "here's my code, here's my requirements" without a specific answerable question. You can do better.

Comment: Sorry I was conversing with another person on a previous question about the same code, I should have been more specific. I have been trying to add a set for my toppings I am needing to write an Add and remove option for the user and that is what I am confused on how to do. Thank you for noticing this

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So here you have your topping methods:

```
public void addTopping(Topping topping) {
    setOfToppings.add(topping);
}

public void removeTopping(Topping topping) {
    setOfToppings.remove(topping);
}

public void addToppings(Topping... toppings) {
    setOfToppings.addAll(Arrays.asList(toppings));
}

public Set<Topping> getToppings() {
    return setOfToppings;
}
```

And here's how you use them in your test code:

```
// use constructor 1
Pizza vegieCrunch = new Pizza();
vegieCrunch.setCrustType(Crust.THIN_AND_CRISPY);
vegieCrunch.setPizzaSize(Size.MEDIUM);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
vegieCrunch.addTopping(Topping.MUSHROOMS);
vegieCrunch.addTopping(Topping.HAM);
vegieCrunch.addToppings(Topping.GREEN_PEPPERS, Topping.PEPPERONI);
vegieCrunch.removeTopping(Topping.HAM);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```